# How to get "unfiltered" array items?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array which I filter by calling `myItems.filter(filterFunction1)` and get some items from it.

Then I want to run another filtering function `filterFunction2` against the remaining items which were not selected by `filterFunction1`.

Is that possible to get the remaining items that were left out after calling a filtering function?

Comment: Not in a single shot, you probably shouldn't use filter at all if you need to get unfiltered items as well.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for `reduce` and binning the items into a final object `{ filtered: [...], unfiltered: [] }`.

Comment: I actually need both filtered and unfiltered items but separated into arrays.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov then you likely want to use `reduce` or a generator or whatever, so that you would loop the array only once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to rerun the filter with an inverted predicate, which seems wasteful. You should `reduce` the items instead and bin them into one of two bins:

```
const result = arr.reduce((res, item) => {
    res[predicate(item) ? 'a' : 'b'].push(item);
    return res;
}, { a: [], b: [] });
```

`predicate` here is the callback you'd give to `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no one-step solution based on `filter`. Still the solution is a simple one-liner:

Here's an example

```js
const arr = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ];

const filtered = arr.filter(x=>!!(x%2))

const remaining = arr.filter(x=>!filtered.includes(x))

console.log(filtered, remaining);
```

Comment: That is an extremely wasteful approach.

Comment: @deceze I haven't done performance testing, but you are probably right. Still the performance cost often is neglectable and this is probably more readable than a complex reduce call.

Answer (score 0):

You could map an array of flags and then filter by the flags values.

```js
const cond = v => !(v % 2);

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    flags = array.map(cond),
    result1 = array.filter((_, i) => flags[i]),
    result2 = array.filter((_, i) => !flags[i]);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `Array.reduce`.

```
const myItems = [...];

const { result1, result2 } = myItems.reduce(
  (result, item) => {
    if (filterFunc1(item)) {
      result.result1.push(item);
    } else if (filterFunc2(item)) {
      result.result2.push(item);
    }
    return result;
  },
  { result1: [], result2: [] },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `reduce`, you may want to iterate the array once and acquire the filtered and unfiltered items in a single shot, using a plain efficient `for..of` loop:

```js
function filterAndDiscriminate(arr, filterCallback) {
  const res = [[],[]];
  for (var item of arr) {
    res[~~filterCallback(item)].push(item);
  }
  return res;
}

const [unfiltered, filtered] = filterAndDiscriminate([1,2,3,4,5], i => i <= 3);
console.log(filtered, unfiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way more simple and readable way to do this:

```
const array1 = []
const array2 = []
itemsToFilter.forEach(item => item.condition === met ? array1.push(challenge) : array2.push(challenge))
```