# Get values from arrays inside nested objects, compare and return the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, ecmascript-5

I am trying to loop through a nested object that looks like this:

```
let obj = {
  cols: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'dob', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'address', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'income', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'vehicleNumber', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'assets', type: 'Number' }
  ],
  row: [ 
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo', 
      columns: ['name', 'address', 'assets'], 
    } 
  ]
}
```

I am using the logic below to loop through the object's arrays, compare if they are equal, and if they are, I am returning them in an array. I am trying to return the entire object inside the cols key though. For e.g, if there are matching elements inside cols array' name value with the row array's columns key's value, (cols.name === row.columns[element], if there is a match return cols object)

```
//loop through the obj and get the keys before this
let cols = cols.map(col => col.name);
let row = row.map(ind => ind.columns);
let rowNamesFlattened = [].concat.apply([], row);
let matchingCols = cols.filter(element => row.includes(element));
```

The `matchingCols` object now has the matching names, but I want to ultimately return their type as well. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `filter` directly on the `cols` array. However here I assumed that `row` array has only 1 element

```js
let obj = {
  cols: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'dob', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'address', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'income', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'vehicleNumber', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'assets', type: 'Number' }
  ],
  row: [ 
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo', 
      columns: ['name', 'address', 'assets'], 
    } 
  ]
}

let matchingCols = obj.cols.filter(({name}) => obj.row[0].columns.includes(name))

console.log(matchingCols)
```

In case multiple elements present inside `row` array. can use `flatMap` to get flattened list of columns and then the same procedure as above

```js
let obj = {
  cols: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'dob', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'address', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'income', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'vehicleNumber', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'assets', type: 'Number' }
  ],
  row: [ 
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo', 
      columns: ['name', 'address', 'assets'], 
    },
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo2', 
      columns: ['dob','name'], 
    } 
  ]
}

let filtered = obj.cols.filter(({name}) => obj.row.flatMap(ind => ind.columns).includes(name))

console.log(filtered)
```

Another solution to get both matched and unmatched in one go using  `reduce`. so no need 2 filter calls. referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473075/13583510)

```js
let obj = {
  cols: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'dob', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'address', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'income', type: 'String' },
    { name: 'vehicleNumber', type: 'Number' },
    { name: 'assets', type: 'Number' }
  ],
  row: [ 
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo', 
      columns: ['name', 'address', 'assets'], 
    },
    { 
      name: 'randomInfo2', 
      columns: ['dob','name'], 
    } 
  ]
}

let flatted = obj.row.flatMap(ind => ind.columns);

const result = obj.cols.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[flatted.includes(curr.name) ? 'match' : 'unmatch'].push(curr);
    return acc;
}, { match: [], unmatch: [] });

console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP, this will work,  just keep in mind here we are accessing row using index, you will have to loop over row array if there are multiple values present. :) +1 :D

Comment: yep that needs to be mentioned. thanks

Comment: This is a brilliant approach, thanks OP. Like @ShivamSood mentioned, is there a way to handle rows dynamically if there are multiple values instead of another nested loop? Also, is there a way to return the remaining elements in a separate array of objects?

Comment: @boomchickawawa i did some edit for multiple elements in row

Comment: final result is a seperate array of objects. im not mutating the original data

Comment: what i mean is, the `matchingCols` variable would have an array of matched objects. is it possible to return the remaining objects of `obj.cols` and store it in a separate variable?

Comment: remaining means unmatched? can you give an example case and output

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for the vague language. the unmatched objects in an separate array

Comment: so basically the unmatched would be `vehicleNumber`, `income` and `dob` in the first code snippet example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242697/discussion-between-boomchickawawa-and-cmgchess).

Comment: @boomchickawawa a ! inside before your filter condition will give unmatching elements

Comment: @boomchickawawa found another method to get in single call

Comment: brilliant! tysm